# Identificacion de clases en actividad de java

Tags: java

¿Alguien podría decirme que más clases hay en este enunciado?

Una tienda online necesita un método programado que según el precio base de un artículo le calcule el precio definitivo teniendo en cuenta ciertos descuentos especiales:

Si el precio es hasta 9 €, no hay descuento. Si el precio es entre 10 y 50 euros, hay un descuento pequeño del 10%. Si el precio es 51 euros o más, hay un descuento mayor del 20%. Si eres trabajador senior (más de 10 años de trabajo) de la tienda, se te ofrece un descuento aplicado del 20% adicional al precio definitivo calculado según el precio base.

De cada trabajador se desea guardar el nombre, edad y fecha de contratación. Crea un método en Java en la clase principal, que reciba el importe base y un trabajador (si lo es; en caso contrario, enviar ‘null’).

Cada vez que se calcule un importe sin excepciones, además, en segundo plano, se debe mostrar por consola el mensaje “Importe calculado con éxito”. Si se recibe un trabajador, mostrar los datos de ese trabajador seguidamente por consola también.

En el main() generar tres llamadas al método para probar su funcionamiento.

Sé que está la clase trabajador, mi duda es si hay alguna más como por ejemplo la clase tienda y que de esta herede artículo y trabajador. ¿Alguien me ayuda?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Según lo leído en tu pregunta habría al menos tres clases: `Articulo, Trabajador, Tienda`. En cuanto a que alguna de ellas herede de otras, pues no. La herencia es una cosa metafísica digamos, y para entenderla, tienes que pensar en el *ser* de las cosas. Un `Articulo` no es una `Tienda` ni un `Trabajador`. Para que lo entiendas mejor, `Trabajador` podría heredar de una clase `Persona` **porque comparte propiedades comunes del ser `Persona`** como `nombre`, `apellido`, `fechaNacimiento`, etc. De todos modos, no planteas un problema concreto en tu pregunta y podría ser cerrada.

Answer (score 0):

Opino que solo necesitas una clase "trabajador y una clase "articulo", hacer una clase solo para "tienda" lo veo innecesario ya que no va a aportar ningún atributo que no sean de "trabajador" o de "articulo", por lo que opino que en este caso no estaríamos hablando de herencia

Comment: Recordá que las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan [cerradas](/help/closed-questions). Aguardá a que el OP (autor de la pregunta) delimite su pregunta a un problema específico.